# Probability Distribution Type for Number of People Who Play Pokemon Go

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

**Problem**
We perform an experiment where we ask 10 students, who are a representative sample of the Informatics department, whether or not they play Pokémon GO. The number of students who play Pokémon GO is best modeled by:

**Answer**
I narrowed the search down to **Discrete Distributions** (Binomial, Bernoulli, Poisson, Geometric). After going through the question again I eliminated Geometric from the list because we're not looking for the first person who plays Pokemon Go. I also eliminated Bernoulli because we have more than 1 trial. It came down to **Binomial** and **Poisson**. I can't tell if being bound to the **Informatics Department** is a spatial condition that validates the use of Poisson. 
However, Binomial requires me to choose $X$ amount of people to calculate a probability, which isn't shown in the problem at all. Does this mean **Poisson** is the answer?

Comment: If the Department has lots of students, binomial is reasonable, $n=10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$ we have a Bernoulli distribution, the $n=1$ special case of the binomial distribution. Independence for the students implies the binomial distribution is appropriate in general. A Poisson approximation of the binomial distribution is reasonable when there are many students, who are each unlikely to play *Pokémon Go*. In fact, the Poisson distribution is typically motivated as the high-n limit of the binomial distribution at fixed mean.

Comment: Just for the bad people!